# TamperMonkey userscript doesn't fire DOMContentLoaded event

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

This is a TamperMonkey userscript.  Why doesn't "HELLO" popup?  I am running Google Chrome on Ubuntu.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        http://*/*
// @match        https://*/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    alert("HELLO");
  });
```

Comment: [`document`, not `window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded).

Comment: I just tried that, still doesn't work.

Comment: For a basis of comparison, just doing `alert("HELLO");` works.

Comment: add `// @run-at document-start` to your header will help, check out [the specification](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40run-at) for more details

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        http://*/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    if (document.readyState == "complete" || document.readyState == "loaded" || document.readyState == "interactive") {
        alert("Already Loaded");
    } else {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
            alert("Just Loaded");
        });
    }
})();
```

Borrowed from [How to detect if DOMContentLoaded was fired](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9457891/1541563).

Comment: Thanks, this works.  Is the problem that DOMContentLoaded fires before TamperMonkey starts running on the page?

Comment: @JoshuaMeyers that is correct, as you should be able to deduce from the alerted text.