# Cannot add event listener in Google Colaboratory output cell

Tags: javascript, events, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I tested some javascript library for data visualization. It didn't run. So I tried the simplest thing until I found that the problem is with `window.addEventListener`.

Start with import

```
from IPython.display import HTML
```

Then, this code can run.

```
HTML('''
<script>
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Hello'))
</script>
''') # Hello
```

But this one doesn't run.

```
HTML('''
<script>
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Hello'))
});
</script>
''')
```

Did I make a mistake somewhere?

How can I add an event listener properly for output in Colab?

Comment: Maybe `DOMContentLoaded` simply doesn't fire? You might check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457891/how-to-detect-if-domcontentloaded-was-fired

Comment: @CertainPerformance `DOMContentLoaded` should always fire when the page is finished loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your HTML output is inserted into the output iframe, the DOMContentLoaded event has already fired. Loading the output frame is a prerequisite for handling output items like the `HTML` object.