# QuerySelector null on elements that exists on local storage and visible DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, local-storage, innerhtml, queryselectall

I have a simple table, in that table, each row is added (using innerHTML) with data from local storage. Each row contains an edit button. When I querySelectAll edit buttons with the class name it returns null that doesn't make sense.

Here, *Total_Users* is the stored array of objects, each object pass to the *addToUserList()* that apply innerHTML that contains a button. With the document loaded, data is presented but querySelectorAll returns null in search of "editButt". As data is presented in DOM, several buttons should be a result which I didn't get...

```
// DOM
class Show {
    static addToUserList(user) {

        let list = document.querySelector('#table-body'); //just a table
        let row = document.createElement('tr');
        row.innerHTML = `<td>${user.name}</td>
        <td>${user.email}</td>
        <td>${user.phone}</td>
        <td>${user.role}</td>
        <td class="text-center mx-auto"> <i class="fa fa-edit text-success btn editButt" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#edit"></i> </td>`;
        list.appendChild(row);
    }
}

//Fill with previously stored data
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', Load_Users);

function Load_Users() {
    let Total_Users;
    if (localStorage.getItem('Total_Users') === null) {
        Total_Users = [];
    } else {
        Total_Users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Total_Users'));
    }
    Total_Users.forEach(item => {
        Show.addToUserList(item);
    })
}

// querySelector editButt
// find nothing here
let editElem = document.querySelectorAll('.editButt');
console.log(editElem);
```

Comment: Inside Load_Users() function this line of code returns the array of objects presented in Local Storage

Answer (score 1):

You could try first selecting the "#table-body", and then use the querySelectorAll() to search through the table element. Try something along these lines:

```
let container = document.querySelector('#table-body');
let editElem = document.querySelectorAll('.editButt');
```

If that doesn't work, try using the old-fashioned getElementsByClassName selector, I've had this problem with the querySelectorAll() before and I ended up using something like this:

```
var editElem = document.getElementsByClassName('editButt');
```

### If none of that works for you, I suggest adding an id to whichever element you're trying to select. That way you know for a fact you're selecting that specific element.

[document.querySelectorAll() | MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

---

[document.getElementsByClassName() | MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

---

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the event "DOMContentLoaded" is ready, for example:

```
if (document.readyState === "complete" || document.readyState === "loaded") {
    // document is already ready to go
    // your query selector here: 
    let editElem = document.querySelectorAll('.editButt');
    console.log(editElem);
}
```

check the answer to this question in detail here:

[How to detect if DOMContentLoaded was fired](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9457996/9676887)

Answer (score 0):

Inside the load_Users() function the querySelector works fine Here:

```
function Load_Users(){
   ....
   editElements();
   deleteElements();
}

function editElements(){
   let editElem = document.querySelectorAll('.editButt');
   console.log(editElem.length);
   ...
}
```