# Render API/Json data using Async Await in Html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to render JSON data in HTML in div with id content in paragraph tags in this format -

ID:XYZ

Username : ABC

Age : Kd

How can I do it ?? I am new in async-await, can someone help me ??

./user.json  file

```
[
{
    "id":1002,
    "username":"dcode",
    "age":30

},

{

"id":1140,
"username":"otheruser",
"age":41
}


]
```

```
//My async await 
async function loadUsers()
{
    const response = await fetch("./user.json");
    return response.json();

}

document .addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',async()=>{
try{
    users = await loadUsers();

}
catch (e)
{
    console.log("ERROR");
    console.log(e);

}

console.log(users);



})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fetching the data you can create paragraph elements, add user data to the `innerText` of the paragraph element and then append it to the div container having id `content`

```js
async function loadUsers() {
  const response = await fetch("./user.json");
  return response.json();
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => {
  try {
    const users = await loadUsers();
    const divContainer = document.getElementById('content');
    users.forEach(user => {
        const paragraphElem = document.createElement('p');
        paragraphElem.innerText = `ID: ${user.id} \n Username: ${user.username} \n Age: ${user.age}`;
        divContainer.appendChild(paragraphElem);
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('ERROR');
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you also help me with this query--->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69326368/display-drop-box-item-selected-price-from-api

Comment: @NatashaAnderson It is already answered and seems your problem is resolved. Please let me know in case you need any other help.

Answer (score 0):

> You can't control when your script is going to execute, At times it's
> possible that DOMContentLoaded was already fired by the time you get a
> chance to listen for the event.
>
> To take that into consideration, your code needs to check if
> DOMContentLoaded was already fired and, if so, proceed to execute
> right away whatever it is that needed to wait for DOMContentLoaded:

Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457891/how-to-detect-if-domcontentloaded-was-fired)

A working example of what you want to achieve.

```js
//My async await
async function loadUsers() {
  let response = await fetch("https://api.sampleapis.com/wines/reds");
  return response.json();
}

let users;

async function runWhenPageIsFullyParsed() {
  console.log("on content load");
  try {
    users = await loadUsers();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("ERROR");
    console.log(e);
  }

  console.log(users);
}

if (document.readyState === "complete") {
  runWhenPageIsFullyParsed();
} else {
  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", runWhenPageIsFullyParsed);
}
```

Note: I have used an external link here for example.